# mysql insert time

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

I'm making a comment box. but i want so when people click submit comment, then they time get logged into mysql togheter with the other info i logg. heres the code i use:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) //===When I will Set the Button to 1 or Press Button to register
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 5 ){
echo "Slow down! you can only send 5 comments a day";

}else{

mysql_query ("insert into comment(username,comment)values('$username','$comment')");
header('location: succes_comment.php');
}
}
?>
```

so if a user clicked that, then the mysql time colonnum got the username, comment and the time he sent the comment.

Comment: the question is what is the code for time? or so that the time get inserted?

Comment: make a field called `timestamp` in your database and make the default value as `CURRENT_TIME` thats all you got to do!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the datetime column in your database. lets name it 'time_posted' Then when you insert a row you do it like this:

```
 insert into comment(username,comment, time_posted)values('$username','$comment', NOW())
```

and when you check that a user submits at most, let say 1 comment in a minute, you do this :

```
  SELECT username FROM comment WHERE username='$username' and time_posted = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

so you will get the amount of messages he placed in the last minute, and by that you can prevent him from posting more.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
ALTER TABLE `comment`
  ADD `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, COMMENT='';
```

New query:

```
SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE
  `username` = '$username' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: True. This is even simpler ;)